# how can a NanAsyncWorker parameter be "undeclared identifier"

Tags: c++, node.js, node.js-addon, node.js-nan

I have this code
(from https://github.com/nodejs/nan/tree/master/examples/async_pi_estimate )

```
class PiWorker : public NanAsyncWorker {
public:
    PiWorker( NanCallback *callback, NanUtf8String sz_QMN )
    : NanAsyncWorker( callback ) {}     
    ~PiWorker() {}

void Execute() {
    printf( "(cc)>>>> qmn [%s].\n", sz_QMN ) ; .... line 52
```

... and compiler says

```
..\mqconn.cc(52): error C2065: 'sz_QMN' : undeclared identifier
```

How can it be ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you declare `sz_QMN` as private member?
From the nan example, the `Execute()` function only access the private members.
You can initialize the `sz_QMN` private member in your constructor:

```
public:
PiWorker(NanCallback *callback, NanUtf8String sz_QMN)
: NanAsyncWorker(callback), sz_QMN(sz_QMN) {}
```